# Trying to hide modal in ts file but its not working at all

Tags: jquery, angular

Hi guys i'm working with angular and trying to hide modal after performing functionality but getting
**ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).modal is not a function**

HTML Code:

```
<div class="modal fade custom-modal-setting" id="drag-and-drop-image" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload-card-details',
    templateUrl: './upload-card-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-card-details.component.css']
})

export class UploadCardDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
public readURL() {
        var input = document.getElementById("file-upload-area");
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#uploaded-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#drag-and-drop-image').modal('hide');
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

there is a line which is commonly used to hide a modal in javascript **$('#drag-and-drop-image').modal('hide');** but getting error in angular

Comment: I don't think `.modal(` exist in core jQuery. I guess thats from some plugin and you forgot to somehow import or include it ?

Comment: Or you have typo. You might meant to use `$('#drag-and-drop-image').hide();` or `$('.modal').hide()` ?

Comment: Hi @kevtis i have used both the commands .hide() and .modal('hide')
.hide() gives me no error but not working as well means modal does not hide
and .modal('hide') gives me an error i have mentioned in my Question

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this use of modal function is part of a *Bootstrap Modal Plugin*, you can find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp).

Maybe you should try to load the library [bootstrap.js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/) or the minified one ?

Comment: Hi @eldala07 i have now installed bootstrap using npm and than included it in angular.json file's script section but still getting same error

i tried to include modal in ts file as well using `import * as modal  from 'bootstrap';` but did'nt worked :(

Answer (score 0):

`.modal()` is not a method of `jQuery` so Try:

```
$('#drag-and-drop-image').hide();
```

Comment: when i was using `.modal('hide')`  i was getting error which i have mentioned in my question but when i used `.hide() ` the error was removed but modal did'nt closed

Comment: @YasirMehmood have you included `bootstrap.js` in your index.html or angular.json file?

Comment: yes i have included it sharing the code of angular.json `"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]`

Comment: @YasirMehmood if you just write the command .modal('hide') in browser console on your site, what does it say?

Comment: when i use .modal('hide') it give this **ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).modal is not a function**